# Is it possible to get only the first character of a String?

Tags: java, char

I have a for loop in Java.

```
for (Legform ld : data)
{
    System.out.println(ld.getSymbol());
}
```

**The output of the above for loop is**

> Pad
>
> CaD
>
> CaD
>
> CaD

Now my question is it possible to get only the first characer of the string instead of the whole thing Pad or CaD

For example if it's Pad I need only the first letter, that is P
For example if it's CaD I need only the first letter, that is C

Is this possible?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`String` has a `charAt` method that returns the character at the specified position. Like arrays and `List`s, `String` is 0-indexed, i.e. the first character is at index `0` and the last character is at index `length() - 1`.

So, assuming `getSymbol()` returns a `String`, to print the first character, you could do:

```
System.out.println(ld.getSymbol().charAt(0)); // char at index 0
```

Comment: The only problem with this is the resulting value is a `char` not a `string`.

Answer (score 98):

Use `ld.charAt(0)`. It will return the first `char` of the `String`.

With `ld.substring(0, 1)`, you can get the first character as `String`.

Answer (score 12):

The string has a substring method that returns the string at the specified position.

```
String name="123456789";
System.out.println(name.substring(0,1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I am taking Mobile No From EditText It may start from +91 or 0 but i am getting actual 10 digits.
Hope this will help you.

```
              String mob=edit_mobile.getText().toString();
                    if (mob.length() >= 10) {
                        if (mob.contains("+91")) {
                            mob= mob.substring(3, 13);
                        }
                        if (mob.substring(0, 1).contains("0")) {
                            mob= mob.substring(1, 11);
                        }
                        if (mob.contains("+")) {
                            mob= mob.replace("+", "");
                        }
                        mob= mob.substring(0, 10);
                        Log.i("mob", mob);

                    }
```

Answer (score -4):

**Answering for C++ 14,**

Yes, you can get the first character of a string simply by the following code snippet.

```
string s = "Happynewyear";
cout << s[0];
```

if you want to store the first character in a separate string,

```
string s = "Happynewyear";
string c = "";
c.push_back(s[0]);
cout << c;
```

Answer (score -10):

Java strings are simply an array of char.  So, char c = s[0] where s is string.

Comment: That is C or C++. In Java, it would work, but only if you cast the string to a char array. For example, like this: `s.toCharArray()[0];`